# Why it prints false in this case?

Tags: c++, hex, cout

```
int main() {
    char * a = (char*)malloc(1);
    *a = 0xff;
    std::cout << (*a == 0xff);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does it print 0 instead of 1?

Comment: When you build, you don't get a *warning* from the compiler? Then perhaps you should add flags to display more warnings. The problem is most likely to do with that `char` can be `signed` or `unsigned`, and in your case most likely `signed`.

Comment: No warnings (Codeblocks)

Comment: Go to global compiler settings and add warning options (gcc: `-Wall -Wpedantic  -Wextra`) (search what is appropriate for your compiler) (and find out, which one you use, codeblocks is not compiler, but IDE). It certainly should warn you about the signed/unsigned comparison (edit: or constant overflow... hehe.. argh). The gcc will emit: *"warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]"* and with -Wextra: *"warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]"*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`0xff` is an integral constant and its type is `int`. To do the comparison, `*a` would have to be promoted to an `int`.

It would appear that `char` is signed on your platform. So when promoting to an integer, there's going to be sign extension.

Assuming 32 bit `int`, you are comparing `0xffffffff` to `0x000000ff`.

Switching to `unsigned char` will give the result you want reliably.

Comment: @JaroslavTavgen - Happy to help. Btw, you should check your compiler switches. [Most **will warn you**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/259265e9c0bc7de2).

Comment: Thank you, once again! I have turned on the warnings in my compiler and now it shows 2 warnings when compiles that code: "warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]" and "warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]"

Answer (score 0):

0xff in Hex is 255 in Decimal.
char keyword indicates a signed character and its range is from -128 to 127 (inclusive)
**The 255 cannot be stored in char and it overflows. Whatever the resulting value, it is not 0xff.**

Hence, it prints False.

Hope that was helpful! :)

Comment: `char` may either be signed or unsigned